# Python: Using functions to read lines from csv files and extract data from these lines

Tags: python, csv

I hope somebody might help me with this. Please help me! :)

Data from csv-file:

```
Region      Municipio   laboratorio clinica Sospechosos Total casos
AMAZONAS    AMAZONAS    0         0          6      6
AMAZONAS    EL ENCANTO  0         0          0      0
ANTIOQUIA   ABEJORRAL   0         0      2      2
ANTIOQUIA   ABRIAQUI    0         0          0      0
ARAUCA  ARAUCA          6         13     0      19
ARAUCA  DESCONOCIDO 0          0     0       0
ARAUCA  ARAUQUITA   1         12     0      13
ARAUCA  TAME            2          1     0       3
ATLANTICO   ATLANTICO   0          0     4       4
ATLANTICO   BARANOA         1          9     0      10
AMAZONAS    PUERTO          0          0     0       0
AMAZONAS    TARAPACA    0          0     0       0
BOLIVAR ARENAL          0          0     29     29
BOLIVAR ARJONA          3          8     0      11
```

Task 1)

I need to create a function - extractDataFromFile(filename) that reads all the lines/rows in the csv-file.

Task 2)

The next function getRegionData(), must extract data (laboratorio, clinica, Sospechosos, Total casos) from each region using the previous function.

I have worked on this for a week now and I'm pretty lost. :( Hope you guys can help me ;)

Comment: What did you try so far? Please specify that in your question

Comment: first problem that is not a valid csv file

Comment: You should learn how to use "python i/o" to read and write documents; and learn how to use "pandas" to organize and display your data in DataFrames.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open(filename) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    headers = lines[0].split("  ")
    for line in lines[1:]:
        data = [s.strip() for s in line.split("  ") if s]
```

`data` contains the info and `headers` the headers

also you can use the `pandas` and `csv` modules to do this

Comment: this answer would work if the file was formatted correctly but the header has too many splits (Sospechosos Total casos) will be 3 elements, and the data line 2 has (AMAZONAS    EL ENCANTO) which will throw off the indexes - this is why  i made the comment about it not being a valid csv - and simple split is problematic

Comment: @gkusner you are right but spliting on 2 spaces should be ok if  their is no counter example